# Excel reporting - function hlookup doesn't work in nested for loop

Tags: vba

I've got a problem. I' m trying to match specific values by item_id using hlookup function. But this function does not return specified value.
Here is the code of my macro :

```
Sub create_report()

Dim itemWs As Worksheet, offerWs As Worksheet, testWs As Worksheet
Dim itemLastRow As Long, offerLastRow As Long
Dim offerLastCol As Long, itemLastCol As Long
Dim dataRng As Range

Set itemWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot")

Set offerWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offers")

Set testWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testowy")

itemLastRow = itemWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
offerLastRow = offerWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

offerLastCol = offerWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
itemLastCol = itemWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set dataRng = testWs.Range("I3:AF" & 4)


'For x = 2 To 7
    'On Error Resume Next
    'itemWs.Range("I" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(itemWs.Range("C" & x).Value & itemWs.Range("B" & x).Value, dataRng, 3, 0)
'Next x



Sheets("Testowy").Range(Sheets("Testowy").Cells(offerLastCol - 1, 1), Sheets("Testowy").Cells(itemLastRow + 4, itemLastCol)) = _
Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Range(Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("nn_rfx_compare_per_lot").Cells(itemLastRow, itemLastCol)).Value

Sheets("Testowy").Range(Sheets("Testowy").Cells(1, itemLastCol), Sheets("Testowy").Cells(offerLastCol - 2, offerLastRow - 2)) = _
WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Offers").Range(Sheets("Offers").Cells(1, 2), Sheets("Offers").Cells(offerLastRow, offerLastCol - 1)))

Dim lastTestCol As Long
lastTestCol = testWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim ColumnLetter As String

For Row = 6 To 11

    For Col = 9 To lastTestCol
    On Error Resume Next
        testWs.Cells(Row, Col).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(testWs.Range( _
        "I4:AF4"), WorksheetFunction.Match(testWs.Cells(Row, 3).Value, testWs.Cells(3, Col), 0))
        
        'Match(testWs.Cells(Row, 3), dataRng, 1)
        
        'HLookup(testWs.Cells(Row, 3), dataRng, 2, 0)
        
    Next Col

Next Row
```

End Sub

In this link there is shown a report which I'd like to organise
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rYvG.png)

Comment: Try to change `Set dataRng = testWs.Range("I3:AF" & 4)`. The row in which you are looking must be the first in the search range

Comment: Ok,that's work, but it returns duplicates prop_id for all of the records.If youhave any ideas, I would be very glad

Comment: you want to get `sup_id` row values?

Comment: Yes and I would like also to eliminate duplicates. I don't know if hlookup is desirable for my prtoblem

Comment: To find a column, you can use `Application.Match()`, then select the cell in the found column and the desired row. You can use the built-in `Collection` object or [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to detect duplicates

Comment: Ok I have used your solution. But Vba is assigning first met sup_id to all filtered records and I don't know why. e.g. sup_id equals 381, but the value filled in cell is 330

Comment: 1. Can you update the code in the question? 2. `.HLookup` searches the first matched value.

Comment: I have updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task and conditions are not completely clear (what to do with duplicates, whether they can occur, whether `item_id` is unique and so on).
If, for example, you need to select `sup_id` corresponding to `item_id`, it can be done by the following code:

```
Set item_id_rng = testWS.Range("I3:AF3")
For Row = 6 To 11
    ' search `item_id` in Range("I3:AF3")
    find_col = Application.Match(testWS.Cells(Row, 3).Value, item_id_rng, 0)
    If IsNumeric(find_col) Then ' if found, get correspondent value from  correspondent row
        'output to 9 column (empty area), for example
        testWS.Cells(Row, 9).Value = item_id_rng(1).Offset(-1, find_col - 1)
    End If
Next Row
```

[image]

As for the task as a whole, it would be good if you formulated the conditions of the task and placed an image of the result